# Proofs for off-axis focal lengths of a concave mirror

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, geometry, vision

I am reading "Fundamentals of Optics" the 4th edition, by Francis Jenkins. The book mentions a conclusion for off-axis concave mirrors:

[image]

That is, depending on:

- mirror radius of curvature $r$,
- off-axis incident angle $\phi$,

the equivalent focal lengths of an off-axis mirror are:
$$
\begin{align}
f_T & = \frac{r}{2}\cos\phi, \tag{focal length at the tangential plane} \\
f_S & = \frac{r}{2}\frac{1}{\cos\phi}. \tag{focal length at the sagittal plane}
\end{align}
$$

I would like to verify this by hand. The book attaches the below figure. Deriving $f_T$ is easy, but I am struggling with $f_S$.

Can anyone provide complete proof for deriving the two focal lengths?

[image]

Comment: Look up the Monk reference p51-52 on [Archive.org](https://archive.org/details/light032647mbp/page/n65/mode/2up).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment of @Farcher, the proof by Monk is on the Page 424-425 of [link](https://archive.org/details/light032647mbp/page/n411/mode/2up). Monk's proof requires a set of law of sines and multiple steps for calculations.

Fortunately, as shown below, my proof is much concise compared to the original one by Monk.

###### Assumptions and conventions

1. We consider parallel rays hitting the concave mirror.
2. We consider the mirror's radius of curvature $r$ is much larger than the mirror's diameter, and use the small angle approximation: $\tan\theta \approx \theta \approx \sin\theta$ for $\theta \ll 1$.
3. We denote the 3D space in $(x,y,z)$, with the $x$-$z$ plane and the $y$-$z$ plane being the sagittal and the tangential plane, respectively.
4. We abuse the sign convention in optics and $r$ is always positive.

Given these, we denote the following vectors:

- Incident ray direction $\mathbf{d} = (0, \sin\phi, -\cos\phi)$.
- Central ray reflection direction $\hat{\mathbf{d}} = (0, \sin\phi, \cos\phi)$.

###### Proof for the tangential focal length $f_T = \frac{r}{2} \cos\phi$

In this case the incident ray and surface normal are on the tengential plane and can be considered in 2D.
Consider a ray intersects the mirror with $(0, y, z)$:

- Surface normal $\mathbf{n} = (0, -y/L, r/L)$, where $|y| \ll r$ and $L = \sqrt{y^2 + r^2} \approx r$.

The reflectance direction $\mathbf{r}$ is given by the law of reflection:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{r}
& = \mathbf{d} - 2(\mathbf{d} \cdot \mathbf{n}) \mathbf{n} \\
& \approx \left( 0, \sin\phi - 2\frac{y}{r} \cos\phi, \cos\phi + 2\frac{y}{r} \sin\phi\right),
\end{align}
where in the approximation we employ $L \approx r$. Let $\theta = 2(y/r)$ and $\mathbf{r} = \left( 0, \sin(\phi - \theta), \cos(\phi - \theta) \right)$.
Compared to the central ray output direction $\hat{\mathbf{d}}$, the angular difference is:
\begin{align}
\Delta\theta 
& \approx \tan(\phi - \theta) - \tan\phi \\
& \approx -\frac{\mathrm{d} \tan\phi}{\mathrm{d} \phi} \cdot\theta \\
& = \frac{-1}{\cos^2\phi} \theta.
\end{align}

This angular difference projection to $y$ is:
$$
\Delta\theta_y = \Delta\theta \cos\phi = -\frac{2y}{r\cos\phi} = -\frac{y}{f_T},
$$
thus $f_T = (r / 2)\cos\phi$.

###### Proof for the sagittal focal length $f_S = \frac{r}{2} \frac{1}{\cos\phi}$

In this case the incident ray and surface normal are not on a plane and needs consideration in 3D.
Consider a ray intersects the mirror with $(x, 0, z)$:

- Surface normal $\mathbf{n} = (-x/L, 0, r/L)$, where $|x| \ll r$ and $L = \sqrt{x^2 + r^2} \approx r$.

The reflectance direction $\mathbf{r}$ is given by the law of reflection:
\begin{align}
\mathbf{r}
& = \mathbf{d} - 2(\mathbf{d} \cdot \mathbf{n}) \mathbf{n} \\
& = \left( -2\cos\phi \frac{x r}{L^2}, \sin\phi, -\cos\phi + 2\cos\phi \frac{r^2}{L^2} \right) \\
& \approx \left( -2\cos\phi \frac{x}{r}, \sin\phi, \cos\phi\right),
\end{align}
where in the approximation we employ $L \approx r$. Compared to the central ray output direction $\hat{\mathbf{d}}$, the angular difference is:
\begin{align}
\Delta\theta 
& \approx -2\cos\phi\frac{x}{r} = -\frac{x}{f_S},
\end{align}
which is also the $x$ projection. Thus$f_S = r / (2\cos\phi)$.